# Why doesn't Heroku detects my Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, git, heroku, deployment, sinatra

I am using the simplest structure and code, as provided by Heroku dev center:

A 'hello.rb' file

```
require 'sinatra'
get '/' do 
  "Hello World"
end
```

A 'config.ru' file

```
require './hello'
run Sinatra::Application
```

A 'gemfile' file

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'sinatra'
```

on terminal I did:

```
$git init
$heroku create
$bundle
$git add . 
$git commit -m "bundle"
$git push heroku master
```

the app work with heroku local but when trying to push ANY Sinatra app always get the same error message:

```
> Enumerating objects: 29, done. Counting objects: 100% (29/29), done.
> Delta compression using up to 12 threads Compressing objects: 100% (25/25), done. 
> Writing objects: 100% (29/29), 5.63 KiB | 1.88 MiB/s, done.
> Total 29 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Compressing source files... done. 
> remote: Building source: 
> remote:  
> remote:  !   No default language could be detected for this app. 
> remote: HINT:This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack to use for this application automatically. 
> remote:           See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks 
> remote:  
> remote:  !  Push failed remote: Verifying deploy... 
> remote:  
> remote: ! Push rejected to sinatrina. remote:
```

Adding procfile or bundlepack always return the same message as above. Am I missing a step?

Comment: https://medium.com/@christine_tran/deploying-sinatra-app-to-heroku-8c64f025db77 I think it might help

Answer (score 0):

Your code is so simple that I guess Heroku is not able to guess the language.
Try to set the buildpack manually with: `heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby --app your_app`.

Note that first you need to install Heroku CLI and run `heroku login` to log in to your account.